# Forcing enum implementors to contain certain elements

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to do the following:

```
public interface Type
{
    // somehow force implementors to have:
    // ONE;
    // TWO;

    public String getName();
}

public enum Type_A implements Type
{
    ONE("A Is One"),
    TWO("A Is Two");

    private String name;

    private Type_A( String name_in )
    {
        name = name_in;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public enum Type_B implements Type
    {
        ONE("B Is One"),
        TWO("B Is Two");

        private String name;

        private Type_B(String name_in)
        {
            name = name_in;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
```

So that I can do the following:

```
 {
    Type type = Type_A;

    type.ONE.getName();
  }
```

I have not been able to do this.

I would guess I need an interface which is specific to enum?

// ignore the following so I can get past the "too much code" filter

Comment: Yes, there is no way to force via an interface that enums have certain values. // Can you please explain your usecase?

Comment: Eclipse gives me an error that TYPE_A cannot be resolved to a variable. And so of course having ```type.ONE.getName()``` is unknown. Also, ONE cannot be resolved, because, of course, it is not in ```Type```. I guess I should add I am using Java 17, and I cannot go higher

Comment: @jmizv It's part of a system where there are different ```Type_?```. I want to retrieve either ```Type_A``` or ```Type_B```, then use the interface ```Type``` in the rest of the code. Otherwise I need a lot of if/else whenever I want a ```Type_?``` element.

Comment: The closest you might get to what you're asking for would probably be a generic interface for "enum getter" objects with `getOne` and `getTwo` methods, but it sounds like a deeper redesign is warranted.

Comment: The ```Type type = Type_A;``` would happen during application start, then used everywhere else

Comment: I guess what I need is a new interface type: ```public interface  enum Type```.

Comment: This could be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). It might help if, as requested in the comment from @jmizv, you explained what problem you think this might solve.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer I have a series of enums which hold basic information about hardware processes. However the program will be running on different hardware. I have enum for each type of hardware (hardware A might return 500, whereas hardware B might be 100 for the same process). I detect that hardware and would want to switch the enum to that hardware. Yes I could do it with HashMaps of classes, however using enum makes it neater (in my opinion). Just use ```Type.A```, rather than a get from a hashmap using static final keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the visitor pattern. That allows you to ensure that the classes which provide the per-enum value behaviour don't miss providing behaviour for any of the enum values, even when new values are added, while not requiring more than one enum type:

```
package com.example.so;

import java.util.Random;

public class Eg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Type.Visitor<String> nameVisitorA = new Type.Visitor<>() {
            @Override
            public String visitONE() {
                return "A is ONE";
            }

            @Override
            public String visitTWO() {
                return "A is TWO";
            }
        };
        Type.Visitor<String> nameVisitorB = new Type.Visitor<>() {
            @Override
            public String visitONE() {
                return "B is ONE";
            }

            @Override
            public String visitTWO() {
                return "B is TWO";
            }
        };
        Type.Visitor<String> theNameVisitor = new Random().nextBoolean() ? nameVisitorA : nameVisitorB;
        System.out.println(Type.ONE.accept(theNameVisitor));
        System.out.println(Type.TWO.accept(theNameVisitor));
    }
}



enum Type {

    ONE {
        @Override
        public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitONE();
        }
    },
    TWO {
        @Override
        public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor) {
            return visitor.visitTWO();
        }
    };

    interface Visitor<T> {
        T visitONE();
        T visitTWO();
    }
    public abstract <T> T accept(Visitor<T> visitor);
}
```

This example randomly chooses a `Type.Visitor` instance and stores a reference to it in a variable which is then used to print the names of the `enum` values.

Comment: Ok, I can see how that might work. However I still need to know if I am using ```nameVisitorA```. Unless ```nameVisitorA``` can be put into a variable, I still need a test to see which one I need to use.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use a variable to hold a visitor which may be A or B.

Comment: Ok, that should work. I still prefer the enum interface option, as it seems cleaner. Maybe some future version? Thanks